# Synonym analyzer not giving results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following custom analyzer defined:

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "products-alike": {
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "product-db"
        ],
        "tokenizer": "standard"
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "product-db": {
        "type": "synonym",
        "synonyms": [
          "Xiaomi,Mi,Mi3,Mi4,Redmi",
          "OnePlus,OnePlusOne,OnePlus1,OnePlus2"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have mapped this to the required field and done the querying. But there are results only for exact matches, like if I query `Xiaomi`, there are results, but `Mi` or `Mi3` won't get me any. Why is this happening and can any one help to make this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to write all your synonyms in lowercase instead of CamelCase, like this:

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "products-alike": {
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "product-db"
        ],
        "tokenizer": "standard"
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "product-db": {
        "type": "synonym",
        "synonyms": [
          "xiaomi,mi,mi3,mi4,redmi",
          "oneplus,oneplusone,oneplus1,oneplus2"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After this, it will work, i.e. if you query for `Mi3`, you'll match all the synonym tokens:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/your_index/_analyze?analyzer=products-alike&pretty' -d 'Mi3'
```

Results:

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "xiaomi",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "mi",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "mi3",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "mi4",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "redmi",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

Comment: whether changing the order of applying filters to filter : ["products-db","lowercase"], yeild the same effect?

Comment: Yes, that might, but that would make you dependent on the exact casing and I wouldn't count on that. It's always preferable to handle everything in lowercase (i.e. comparing apples to apples)